# What is this finite group $G$? including two dihedral groups of order 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions

### What is the name of an order-16 non-abelian group $G$ satisfying the following properties?

Written in the group multiplication on the right:
$$G=\langle a,b,c|a^2=b^2=c^2=1, ac = - ca, bc= -cb, ab = ba\rangle$$

This $G$ is generated by $a,b,c$, while it seems that it contains two kinds of dihedral group of order-8:
$$
D_8=\langle ac, c| (ac)^2=-1, (ac)^4=1, (ac)c=-c(ac), ac = - ca\rangle
$$
$$
D_8=\langle bc, c| (bc)^2=-1, (bc)^4=1, (bc)c=-c(bc), bc = - cb\rangle
$$

The 16 group elements are:
$$\{1,a,b,c,ab,bc,ac,abc,-1,-a,-b,-c,-ab,-bc,-ac,-abc\}$$

Hints:

1. Here are all the 14 kinds of order-16 non-abelian groups: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16
2. I checked all of them above. The only group that seems to contain two dihedral group of order-8 $D_8$ as subgroups, is the $D_{16}$:
   https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D16
   but the group I listed above does not contain an elementary abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$/8. So that was my puzzle.
3. Another possibility is $D_8 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_direct_product_of_D8_and_Z2, in that case, there should be four dihedral group of order-8 $D_8$ as subgroups. But I only identified two of them so far in this $G$.

Thank you in advance for the comments/answers!

Comment: What is $-ca$? Do you mean $(ca)^{-1}$ or is $-1$ a certain element?

Comment: $-ca = (-1) ca$, it is also $- ca =(ca)^{-1}$ because $(ca)^2=-1$ and $(ca)^4=+1$. See all 16 group element listed

Comment: Also note that $D_8*C_4\cong Q_8*C_4$ (central product).

Comment: $ab=ab$ seems to be a typo

Comment: Yes $ab = ba$. Also I thought about 8∗4≅8∗4 (central product), but there are 3 dihedral groups of order 8 there.

Comment: If I missed to identify another one dihedral order 8 group, then i could just confirm it is 8∗4≅8∗4 (central product).

Comment: Answer is $D_8\times C_2$.

Comment: YES, D8 x C2 is correct, there are indeed four total different D8 subgroups. I also noticed earlier. Thanks!