# What is the name of this non-abelian group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, exact-sequence

### What is the name of an order-16 non-abelian group $G$ satisfying the following properties?

Written in the group multiplication on the right:
$$G=\langle a,b,c|a^2=-1, b^2=c^2=1, ac = - ca, bc= -cb, ab =- ba, (-1)^2=1\rangle.$$

**EDIT: The $-1$ is just a group element such that $(-1)^2=+1$.**

This $G$ is generated by $a,b,c$, while it seems that it contains many dihedral groups of order-8:
$D_8$.

The 16 group elements are:
$$G=\{1,a,b,c,ab,bc,ac,abc,-1,-a,-b,-c,-ab,-bc,-ac,-abc\}$$

Hints:

1. Here are all the 14 kinds of order-16 non-abelian groups: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16
2. I am not sure this $G$ contains any quaternion subgroups.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260921/what-is-this-finite-group-g-including-two-dihedral-groups-of-order-8), which is very similar. I suppose that all $14$ cases are too many here, perhaps. What is your goal in the end? Presentations for groups of order $16$?

Comment: Like before, it's not clear what the negation means.

Comment: What does "multiplication on the right" mean? What does $-1$ mean?

Comment: -1 is just another group element such that $(-1)^2=+1$. It shall be clear from reading the proerties above. thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately this was not at all clear from your post. If you want to impose the existence of an element $-1$ whose square is the identity, you need to actually include this generator & relation in your presentation. It seems like you also want $-1$ to be central, so you need to specify that too. Also, the phrase "multiplication on the right" is still confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I edited, **EDIT: The $-1$ is just a group element such that $(-1)^2=+1$.** Also included in the group law properties on the right.

Comment: To ask again: is $-1$ meant to be central in the group?

Comment: Yes ${1,-1}$ are central subgroup, a center $C_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2$. This center commutes with all group elements

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Now that we know which group you're talking about, it's much easier to answer your question.

Comment: I would be interested to know where you came across this notation of a group presentation using negative signs in the relations. I have never seen it before.

Comment: Also asking  "what is the name of this group?" does not usually have an answer. Most groups have not been given names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a precise way to write the presentation you want:

$$\langle a,b,c \mid a^4, b^2, c^2, [a^2, b], [a^2, c], ac = a^2ca, bc = a^2cb, ab = a^2ba \rangle$$

Here I am using $a^2$ to play the role of $-1$. Now I'll just punch this in to GAP:

```
gap> f := FreeGroup("a","b","c");;
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(f);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ a, b, c ]
gap> r := ParseRelators([a,b,c],"a4,b2,c2,[a2,b],[a2,c],ac=a2ca,bc=a2cb,ab=a2ba");;
gap> StructureDescription(f/r);
"C2 x D8"
```

So, this group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2) \times D_8$.

Comment: thanks so much. I see, there are many ways to rewrite the familiar $(ℤ/2)×_8$. +1.